# How to check not null date in spring jpa

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 IF. If No 1, is work for me. Because i wont if data is present and get house keeping == null. for action to update condition,status,and housekeeping.

```
If(getData.isPresent() && bulkUpdate.getHouseKeeping() == null)
```

IF no 2, no work for me. I wont if getData is present and get housekeeping is availabe / not null. For action only to update condition

```
else if(getData.isPresent() && bulkUpdate.getHouseKeeping() != null)
```

Only check 'null', but not for 'not null'. I wont check null and not null is work for me

NB : getData.isPresent = Integer , getHouseKeeping = Date

Full code :

```
Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date today = sdf.parse(sdf.format(now)); 

    RoomBoy updatedData = request.getPayload();

    Optional<RoomBoy> getData = roomBoyRepository.findByIdAndHouseKeeping(updatedData.getId(), updatedData.getHouseKeeping());
    if(getData.isPresent() && updatedData.getHouseKeeping() == null ) {
        RoomBoy oldData = getData.get();

        oldData.setCondition(updatedData.getCondition());
        oldData.setStatus("Done");
        oldData.setHouseKeeping(today);

        roomBoyRepository.saveAndFlush(oldData);
        status.setStatusCode("000");
        status.setStatusDesc("Success");
    }else if(getData.isPresent() && updatedData.getHouseKeeping() != null){
        RoomBoy oldData = getData.get();
        oldData.setCondition(updatedData.getCondition());

        roomBoyRepository.saveAndFlush(oldData);
        status.setStatusCode("000");
        status.setStatusDesc("Success");
    }else{
        status.setStatusCode("001");
        status.setStatusDesc("Data Not Found");
    }
```

Comment: if( getData.isPresent()){
  if( bulkUpdate.getHouseKeeping() == null) { ...
  }else{
 ...
}
Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: can you add in answer

Comment: sure. Is that what you are looking for ? Else you can write the condition that you expect in simple terms . Also what is the yes condition for isPresent() , is it greater than 0 ?

Comment: If you want to check both conditions, remove 'else'

Comment: Please check again my ask post, i add full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced somewhat similar issue with comparing null. Try doing the following :

```
if(getData.isPresent()){
     if(updatedData.getHouseKeeping() == null ) {
        RoomBoy oldData = getData.get();

        oldData.setCondition(updatedData.getCondition());
        oldData.setStatus("Done");
        oldData.setHouseKeeping(today);

        roomBoyRepository.saveAndFlush(oldData);
        status.setStatusCode("000");
        status.setStatusDesc("Success");
    }else{
        RoomBoy oldData = getData.get();
        oldData.setCondition(updatedData.getCondition());

        roomBoyRepository.saveAndFlush(oldData);
        status.setStatusCode("000");
        status.setStatusDesc("Success");
    }
}
else{
        status.setStatusCode("001");
        status.setStatusDesc("Data Not Found");
}
```

Here we have changed the arrangement of if-elseif to nested if-else. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `updatedData.isPresent()` is true when > 0

```
    if(getData.isPresent() > 0){ // When data is present
       RoomBoy oldData = getData.get(); // get room boy data
       if(updatedData.getHouseKeeping() == null){ // if housekeeping is null
          oldData.setStatus("Done");
          oldData.setHouseKeeping(today); // set house keeping 
        } 
       oldData.setCondition(updatedData.getCondition());

       roomBoyRepository.saveAndFlush(oldData);
       status.setStatusCode("000");
       status.setStatusDesc("Success");
    } else{
        status.setStatusCode("001");
        status.setStatusDesc("Data Not Found");
    }
```